# Best way to save the model to use later as "template"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I don't know if template is the right word for this.
I want models which has template boolean true, to be choose-able at the same models form view. And on choose it would fill the form with the chosen models values.

I'm thinking about this solution:

- List the models next to he form which has the template attribute set to true.
- On click load it trough AJAX , and fill the form with the loaded attributes trough javascript.

I'm wondering if there is a better way for this?

Edit.:

Sorry if it wasn't understandable.

Model.rb has boolean attribute :template.
If template is set to true. It is displayed on the form view of the Model.

_form.html.haml:

:collection_select Model.where(:template => true)

and on select, the template model fills, in the new Model's attributes, with the old template Model's attributes.

I would like to find the Rails way for this.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is very difficult to understand, could you try reword it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a class method in your model to find the template record.

```
def self.find_template_record
  template = where(template: true).first
  raise "no template found" if template.nil?
  return template
end
```

In your controller, load the template record and [clone](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html#method-i-clone) it.  Don't use `dup` because that will copy the `id`.

```
def new
  @model = Model.find_template_record.clone
end
```

Comment: Because `clone` "returns a clone of the resource that hasn’t been assigned an id yet" http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html#method-i-clone

Comment: You should put that in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To duplicate an ActiveRecord model, use its `dup` method:

```
@model = @template_model.dup        # create the base
@model.attributes = params[:model]  # override particular attributes
```

Comment: I think `clone` makes more sense than `dup` in this case.